# shopify JSON response to CSV with node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, csv, shopify

I would like to know whats the best way to read json response from Shopify? I'm using node.js installed in my windows machine and have created in my site a private app that helps me connect to admin panel through it.

This is my code called export.js:

```js
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var json2csv = require('json2csv');
var async = require('async');
var _ = require('underscore');
var RateLimiter = require('limiter').RateLimiter;
var flatten = require('flat');

var limiter = new RateLimiter(1, 500);

var apikey = [**********************'];
var password = [***********************'];
var shopname = ['itofficeberat'];

var baseurl = 'https://'+apikey+':'+password+'@'+shopname+'.myshopify.com';;
var numOrders = 0;
var orders = [];

var getOrders = function(page, callback)
{
    request({
        url: baseurl+'/admin/orders.json'+page,
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {

       if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

                var newList = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < body.orders.length; i++)
                {
                    newList.push(flatten(body.orders[i]));
                }
                
                orders = orders.concat(newList);
                console.log('Received page :'+page+' - count: '+newList.length);
                console.log('orders len:'+orders.length);
                console.log();
    }

        callback();    
    })
}

request({
    url: baseurl+'/admin/orders/count.json?status=any',
    json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        numOrders = body.count;
    }
    
    console.log('Total Order Count :'+numOrders);
    console.log();
    var numPages = numOrders / 250;
    var r = _.range(1, numPages+1);
    
    async.forEach(r, function(page, callback) {
        limiter.removeTokens(1, function() {
            getOrders(page, callback);
        })
                
    }, function(err) {
        // Called when all are finished
        console.log('Total orders: '+orders.length)
        
        json2csv( {data: orders, fields : ['buyer_accepts_marketing','cancel_reason']}, 
            function(err, csv) {
                if (err) console.log(err);
                  fs.writeFile('ShopifyOrders.csv', csv, function(err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log('File saved');
                  });
            });
    });
        });
```

// The code above connects to the site, call the url:  baseurl+'/admin/orders.json'+page, 
//  A file ShopifyOrders.csv is created with the fields   fields : ['buyer_accepts_marketing','cancel_reason'] 
//  But there is no other information included in the csv file. Its empty, it should have other information from json response. //
//  Shopify json response is:

```css
{"orders":[{"buyer_accepts_marketing":false,"cancel_reason":null,"cancelled_at":null,"cart_token":"77a4969f441e36e013da6b2fb8131bf5","checkout_token":"dd5013f1596f3413a5877daaffaab8af","closed_at":null,"confirmed":true,"created_at":"2015-04-23T06:50:03-04:00","currency":"ALL","device_id":null,"email":"arensmyzyri@gmail.com","financial_status":"paid","id":407850657,"landing_site":"\/","location_id":null,"name":"#1001","note":null,"number":1,"processed_at":"2015-04-23T06:50:03-04:00","reference":null,"referring_site":"","source_identifier":null,"source_url":null,"subtotal_price":"2000.00","taxes_included":false,"test":true,"token":"6772e391aedcdf798a0e9f4c5cf6e272","total_discounts":"0.00","total_line_items_price":"2000.00","total_price":"2410.00","total_price_usd":"18.52","total_tax":"400.00","total_weight":0,"updated_at":"2015-04-23T06:56:11-04:00","user_id":null,"browser_ip":"79.106.109.210","landing_site_ref":null,"order_number":1001,"discount_codes":[],"note_attributes":[],"processing_method":"direct","source":"checkout_next","checkout_id":485372325,"source_name":"web","fulfillment_status":null,"tax_lines":[{"price":"400.00","rate":0.2,"title":"VAT"}],"tags":"","line_items":[{"fulfillment_service":"manual","fulfillment_status":null,"gift_card":false,"grams":0,"id":711008221,"price":"2000.00","product_id":465783109,"quantity":1,"requires_shipping":true,"sku":"","taxable":true,"title":"My product","variant_id":1221252657,"variant_title":"M \/ White \/ Silver","vendor":"itofficeberat","name":"My product - M \/ White \/ Silver","variant_inventory_management":null,"properties":[],"product_exists":true,"fulfillable_quantity":1,"total_discount":"0.00","tax_lines":[{"price":"400.00","rate":0.2,"title":"VAT"}]}],"shipping_lines":[{"code":"Standard Shipping","price":"10.00","source":"shopify","title":"Standard Shipping","tax_lines":[{"price":"0.00","rate":0.2,"title":"VAT"}]}],"billing_address":{"address1":"22 tetori","address2":"","city":"Berat","company":"dfgfd","country":"Albania","first_name":"arens","last_name":"myzyri","latitude":40.712601,"longitude":19.93848,"phone":"00355","province":"","zip":"5001","name":"arens myzyri","country_code":"AL","province_code":null},"shipping_address":{"address1":"22 tetori","address2":"","city":"Berat","company":"dfgfd","country":"Albania","first_name":"arens","last_name":"myzyri","latitude":40.712601,"longitude":19.93848,"phone":"00355","province":"","zip":"5001","name":"arens myzyri","country_code":"AL","province_code":null},"fulfillments":[],"client_details":{"accept_language":"en-US,en;q=0.8","browser_height":979,"browser_ip":"79.106.109.210","browser_width":1903,"session_hash":"0ade3a3a8f0729310d4de57b9c736e8efa0e44f4604b191c5c0e1d6d333d3f4f","user_agent":"Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/42.0.2311.90 Safari\/537.36"},"refunds":[],"customer":{"accepts_marketing":false,"created_at":"2015-04-23T06:48:36-04:00","email":"arensmyzyri@gmail.com","first_name":"arens","id":383764389,"last_name":"myzyri","last_order_id":null,"multipass_identifier":null,"note":null,"orders_count":0,"state":"disabled","total_spent":"0.00","updated_at":"2015-04-23T06:56:11-04:00","verified_email":true,"tags":"","last_order_name":null,"default_address":{"address1":"22 tetori","address2":"","city":"Berat","company":"dfgfd","country":"Albania","first_name":"arens","id":458239865,"last_name":"myzyri","phone":"00355","province":"","zip":"5001","name":"arens myzyri","province_code":null,"country_code":"AL","country_name":"Albania","default":true}}}]}
```

Comment: According to me; firstly decode JSON response, format it properly into array/object ie remove unwanted column, validate, etc and then use some function to convert array to CSV

Comment: Can you please send me any link that will help me to understand how to decode the server response? i'M doing only GET request
I don't have access to the server, it gives a response in JSON or RAW if I'm using a broswer to open URL

Comment: Use `JSON.parse()` Eg JSON.parse(shopify json response), this will convert JSON string to Object. Then you can retrieve like other simple objects.